# 2008 Mustang Cabin Leak and “Check Charging System”

Tags: ford, battery, charging, mustang, water

Went to go run some errands today and my 2008 Mustang wouldn’t start. Didn’t even sound like the engine was trying to turn over. Lights flashed inside and CD player went absolutely ballistic. The dash said “check charging system” but only for a second before the car shut off again. We’ve been getting some pretty heavy rain and about two days ago, my passenger side floor was completely filled with water. I checked the cowel drain which was empty and changed my air filter. I’m not sure if the two are related. What’s causing this to happen?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the battery voltage? I don't think the two things are related, but don't know for sure.

Comment: Are battery cables and connections corroded with dry powdery deposits? There may be at least two main ground connections; battery to chassis and chassis to engine block. All main power connections may need to be examined. Powdery deposits on battery terminals; dried battery acid. A warm solution of water and baking soda with a toothbrush will dissolve and neutralize battery deposits immediately. Plain water rinse. Check for lose connections and maybe have the battery tested at your favorite auto store selling car batteries for s free test.